# A* Pathfinding Issue With Obstacles in Grid

Tags: java, search, path-finding, a-star, game-development

### Explanation:

After Searching through my code for quite some time and comparing it to the other questions asked on this site, I still could not quite figure out how to fix this issue.

I am currently busy implementing a A* Pathfinding algorithm for a simple 2D grid based game. 
The code is based on this Pseudocode:

```
// A* (star) Pathfinding

// Initialize both open and closed list
  let the openList equal empty list of nodes
  let the closedList equal empty list of nodes

// Add the start node
    put the startNode on the openList (leave it's f at zero)

// Loop until you find the end
  while the openList is not empty

// Get the current node
    let the currentNode equal the node with the least f value
    remove the currentNode from the openList
    add the currentNode to the closedList

    // Found the goal
    if currentNode is the goal
        Congratz! You've found the end! Backtrack to get path

    // Generate children
    let the children of the currentNode equal the adjacent nodes

    for each child in the children

        // Child is on the closedList
        if child is in the closedList
            continue to beginning of for loop

        // Create the f, g, and h values
        child.g = currentNode.g + distance between child and current
        child.h = distance from child to end
        child.f = child.g + child.h

        // Child is already in openList
        if child.position is in the openList's nodes positions
            if the child.g is higher than the openList node's g
                continue to beginning of for loop

        // Add the child to the openList
        add the child to the openList
```

All costs are 1. Heuristic is Manhattan Distance. The start point is the green square, and the end point is the leftmost pink square.

### Issue:

Using example of The start point (5,3)"Green" and end point(3,4)"Pink", the pathfind works fine for that one but as soon as the green square moves one square to the right, the program enters an infinite loop.

Pictures here:

[Start=(5,3),End=(3,4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Nef.jpg)

[Start=(6,3),End=(3,4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQjVt.jpg)

Sample Output:

Before:

```
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=120]
false

java.awt.Point[x=200,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160]
false

java.awt.Point[x=200,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=200]
false

java.awt.Point[x=200,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=200]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=240]
false

java.awt.Point[x=200,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=200]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=240]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=280]
false

java.awt.Point[x=200,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=200]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=240]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=280]
java.awt.Point[x=120,y=320]
true
```

After:

```
java.awt.Point[x=240,y=120]
false

java.awt.Point[x=240,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=160]
false

java.awt.Point[x=240,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=200]
false

java.awt.Point[x=240,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=200]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=240]
false

java.awt.Point[x=240,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=200]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=240]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=280]
false

java.awt.Point[x=240,y=120]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=160]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=200]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=240]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=280]
java.awt.Point[x=200,y=280]
false
```

The output provided is the closed list for each loop in the while. And then a check to see whether or not the current node is the end node or not.

So for some reason it then keeps repeating that. without ever reaching the end.

I will include my code below and any help would be appreciated.

A* algorithm.

```
public Point[] aStar(Map map,Point start, Point end){
        //Returns a list of positions from point start to end.

        //Get map array
        int[][] Mapp = map.getMap();

        //Create astart and end nodes
        Node startNode = new Node(null,start);
        Node endNode = new Node(null,end);


        //Initialize open and closed lists and path list
        ArrayList<Node> open_list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> closed_list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        ArrayList<Point> path = new ArrayList<Point>();

        //Add start node
        open_list.add(startNode);

        //Loop until you find the end
        while(!open_list.isEmpty()){
            //Get this current node
            Node currentNode = open_list.get(0);
            int current_index = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            for(Node node: open_list){
                if(node.getTotal()<currentNode.getTotal()){
                    currentNode = node;
                    current_index = counter;
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            //Pop current node off open list and add to the closed list
            open_list.remove(current_index);
            closed_list.add(currentNode);
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i <closed_list.size() ; i++) {
                System.out.println(closed_list.get(i).getPosition());

            }

            //Goal
            System.out.println(currentNode.equals(endNode));
            if(currentNode.equals(endNode)){
                Node current = currentNode;
                while(current.getParent() != null){
                    path.add(current.getPosition());
                    current = current.getParent();
                }
                //Reverse path
                Point[] pat = path.toArray(new Point[path.size()]);

                return pat;
            }
            //Array of new positions
            Point[] positions = {new Point(0,-40), new Point(0,40),new Point(-40,0),new Point(40,0),new Point(-40,-40), new Point(-40,40),new Point(40,-40), new Point(40,40)};



            //Generate Children
            childrenloop:
            for(Point newPosition:positions){
                //Get node position
                Point node_position = new Point((int)(currentNode.getPosition().getX()+ newPosition.getX()),(int)(currentNode.getPosition().getY()+ newPosition.getY()));
                //System.out.println(node_position);
                //System.out.println(node_position);
                //Contain in Map
                if(node_position.getX()>(map.getxSize()-40)|| node_position.getX()<0 || node_position.getY()>(map.getySize()-40)|| node_position.getY() <0 ){
                    System.out.println("Out of Bounds");
                    continue;
                }else

                //Check Walkable Terrain
                if(mapping[(int)node_position.getX()/40][(int)node_position.getY()/40] != 0){
                    //System.out.println("Not walkable");
                    continue;
                }else {

                    //Create New Node
                    Node new_Node = new Node(currentNode, node_position);

                    //Add to children
                    children.add(new_Node);
                }

            }

            //Loop through children
            outerloop:
            for(Node child : children){
                //System.out.println(child.getPosition());
                //Check if child is on closed list
                for(Node closed_child : closed_list){
                    if (child.equals(closed_child)){
                        continue outerloop;
                    }
                }

                // Generate the  Total, Distance and Heuristic values
                child.setDistance(currentNode.getDistance()+1);
                int heuristic =(int)Math.round ((Math.pow((child.getPosition().x-endNode.getPosition().x),2))+Math.pow((child.getPosition().y-endNode.getPosition().y),2));
                child.setHeuristic(heuristic);
                child.setTotal();

                //Child already in open list
                for(Node open_node:open_list){
                    if(child.equals(open_node)&& child.getDistance()>open_node.getDistance()){
                        continue outerloop;
                    }
                }

                //Add child to open list
                open_list.add(child);
            }



        }

        return null;

    }
```

Node:

```
public class Node {
    //Node class for A*
    Node parent;
    Point position;

    int distance,heuristic,total;

    public Node(Node parent, Point position){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.position  = position;

        this.distance = 0;
        this.heuristic = 0;
        this.total = 0;
    }

    public boolean equals(Node other){
        return this.position.equals(other.position);
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Point getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Point position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public int getHeuristic() {
        return heuristic;
    }

    public void setHeuristic(int heuristic) {
        this.heuristic = heuristic;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal() {
        this.total = heuristic+distance;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return position.toString();
    }
}
```

Map:

```
public class Map {
    final BizarreBazaar game;
    ExploreScreen screen;
    int level;
    int xSize;
    int ySize;
    int[][] map;
    ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    public Map(int level,final BizarreBazaar game,ExploreScreen screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
        this.game = game;
        this.level=level;
        setMap();
    }

    public void setMap(){
        switch(level){
            case 1:
                xSize = 15;
                ySize = 15;
                map = new int[][]{
                                {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                                {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                        };
                entities.add(new Player(game,screen, 5*40, 3*40, 40, 40, 40.0f, new Texture("player.png"),"player"));
                entities.add(new Entity(game,screen, 120, 320, 40, 40, 40.0f, new Texture("enemy.png"),""));
                entities.add(new Entity(game,screen, 400, 400, 40, 40, 40.0f, new Texture("enemy.png"),""));
                entities.add(new Entity(game,screen, 360, 120, 40, 40, 40.0f, new Texture("enemy.png"),""));
                break;
 public ArrayList<Entity> getEntities(){
        return new ArrayList<Entity>(entities);
    }

    public int[][] getMap(){
        return map;
    }

    public int getxSize() {
        return xSize*40;
    }

    public int getySize() {
        return ySize*40;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't read through your code, there's way too much of it.  But this: `as soon as the green square moves one square to the right, the program enters an infinite loop.` Since you're using Manhattan distance, a lot of your squares are going to be an exactly same distance away from the goal.  A* is known to preform very badly if the heuristic returns identical values.  It can't decide which way to go and it can enter an infinite loop.  I'd switch to geometric distance and see if that fixes the problem.  If it does, you'll have to re-jigger your Manhattan distance heuristic a little.

Comment: Thanks, yes my heuristic was what was giving me trouble. After changing to 4 directional movement, the manhattan one worked. And I will be sure to be more defined with my code next time I ask.